# Minimum of the Rastrigin Function

Tags: functions, optimization, roots

In the context of Optimization, the Rastrigin Function is used as a popular example to the test the ability of different Optimization Algorithms to find the global minimum of this function. This because of the Rastrigin Function has many local minimums which have the ability to "confuse" the optimization algorithm being tested:

[image]

**My Question:** No matter the dimension of the Rastrigin Function (e.g. the equation provided above is for a d-dimensional Rastrigin Function), the minimum of the Rastrigin Function are always at X = 0. **Is it possible to show this for the general case (i.e. the Rastrigin Function having an arbitrary number of dimensions) - or is this considered obvious and not even required to prove?**

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

**Reference:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastrigin_function